# Stationarity Tests in R, checking mean, variance and covariance

Tags: r, statistics

### Preamble

I am not sure if this question belongs to `stackoverflow` or `stackexchange`, I posted it on `stackoverflow` as it contains `R`-code. However, you are free to move it, if you feel it belongs to `stackexchange`.

### Question

I was modelling some time-series and played around with different stationarity tests in `R`, when I noticed something strange. Do we have stationarity tests that check for all three components of a stationary time-series (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process): constant mean, constant variance, and constant covariance)?

Simulating some time-series, I found that the usual tests are not capable of finding some non-stationary time-series. Now the question is, am I missing something, or did I get something wrong, or are there better options than the tests mentioned?

### Simulating some data

The first time-series should be stationary, whereas the other 5 are simulated to have either different means, or different variances.

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:1000,

                  # stationary
                  ts1 = rnorm(1000),

                  # random walk
                  ts2 = cumsum(rnorm(1000)), 

                  # jumps in mean
                  ts3 = c(rnorm(200), rnorm(400, mean = 5), rnorm(400)),

                  # jumps in variance
                  ts4 = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(300, sd = 5), rnorm(500), rnorm(100)), 

                  # increasing variance
                  ts5 = sapply(1:1000, function(x) rnorm(1, sd = x/1000)),

                  # variance as a squared function
                  ts6 = sapply(1:1000, function(x) rnorm(1, sd = (x - 500)^2))/1000000)
```

The series look like this. I would say that it is clear that only the first series has a constant mean and variance and that the other series are non-stationary.

[image: Time-series]

### The issues (?) with tests

So far, I looked into 4 different tests: `adf.test`, `Box.test`, `kpss.test`, and `PP.test` (all from the `tseries`-packages.

While a significant p-value in the `adf.test` and the `PP.test` indicates a stationary series, a significant value indicates non-stationarity for the other two tests.

```
library(tseries)
tests <- c("adf.test", "Box.test", "kpss.test", "PP.test")

sapply(tests, function(test){
  apply(dat[, c("ts1", "ts2", "ts3", "ts4", "ts5", "ts6")], 2, function(x) {
    get(test)(x)$p.value
  })
})

# resulting in 
#      adf.test    Box.test kpss.test   PP.test  # stat:non_stat
# ts1 0.0100000 0.386053779      0.10 0.0100000  # 4:0 clearly stat
# ts2 0.4195604 0.000000000      0.01 0.3260713  # 0:4 clearly non-stat
# ts3 0.5467517 0.000000000      0.01 0.0100000  # 1:3 most-likely non-stat
# ts4 0.0100000 0.004360365      0.10 0.0100000  # 2:2 ?!
# ts5 0.0100000 0.033007310      0.10 0.0100000  # 2:2 ?!
# ts6 0.0100000 0.307453035      0.10 0.0100000  # 4:0 stationary ?!
```

While the first series is found to be stationary by all four tests, the tests have issues with the other series, especially series with changing variance are missclassified in many cases.

Do you know if there are better tests that account for changes in variance and/or covariance?

Thank you very much for ideas, thoughts, and solutions.

Comment: `kpss.test` is the one you are looking for, considering you only look for stationary series, if you use `adf.test` or `pp.test` you must know that this functions test is for "trend-Stationary", so its is not what you are looking for. i only use `Box.test` for residuals auto correlation test for Arima models for example. As far i know this test only take care of mean, not variance or covariance.